# How to see compressed and actual size of files on a compressed drive?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, compression

I'm using Windows 7 and installed a hard disk.  When I formatted it I checked the option to enable file compression.

I copied some files onto the hard drive.  How can I see things like the compression ratio, and how much space the files actually take up?

Answer (score 2):

**[TreeSize Free](http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/index.shtml)** is an excellent and (surprise!) free tool that can show you the space a folder is taking up and also supports NTFS compression so you can see how much space a folder is using or how much data is in the folder overall... in the image below the icon to the right of the "KB MB GB" buttons is the one that toggles actual size vs quantity of data.

[image: Treesize Free]

Answer (score 1):

To know this information for a single file, you can right-click, go in Properties, and compare "Size" and "Size on disk":

[image]